# How to write a GraphQL schema directive for a parameter of a query method

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Assume I have a typeDefs as below in GraphQL apollo server

```
const typeDefs = {
  type User {
    name: String
   }
  type Query {
    getUser(ids: [Int]): [User]
  }
}
```

How do I write a custom schema directive so that I can have a check to make sure the array of ids passed in with the getUser method does not have more than 'n' ids.

Please note I'm using apollo server v2.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. How can a client connecting to my graphql apollo server bypass a check that I will have on my server side.

Comment: sorry, I meant query directives

Comment: Can you give me an example. I'm still not sure.

Comment: use `visitInputObject`

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me a simple example based on the example I gave above. Where to declare the directive exactly and other details

Comment: read docs, try/experiment and come back with real problems/real code